# JScript error on runtime semi colon required

Tags: triggers, monodevelop, jscript, unity-game-engine

I've got a short piece of JScript written that will switch a scene when the player collides with an object, however when I try and run the game I get a compiler error, It's saying that it's expecting a semi colon, and as far as I can tell there is a semi colon present, here is my code;

```
 #pragma strict
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

 function OnTriggerEnter(Col : Collider)
 {
     if(Col.tag == Player);
     {
         SceneManager.LoadScene(Win);
     }
 }
```

And here is the error that I'm getting on runtime;

```
 Assets/Scripts/switchScene.js(2,6): UCE0001: ';' expected. Insert a semicolon at the end.
```

Any help and advice given would be appreciated.

***UPDATE***

New code based on suggestions given;

```
#pragma strict
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

function OnTriggerEnter(Col : Collider)
{
    if(Col.gameObject.tag == "Player") {}
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Win");
    }
}
```

The error that I'm getting remains as the one shown above.

Comment: Get rid of the semicolon after the parenthesized test in the `if` statement.

Comment: @cale_b this question is about Unity "JavaScript", which isn't really JavaScript.

Comment: @ethranes - "unityscript' ***is deprecated*** from Unity!  you can not use it!  fortunately c# is much easier, enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

To check for tag you must use:

```
if(Col.gameObject.tag == "tagname") {}
```

for name is `gameObject.name` and if you have a `GameObject` var just `gameObject == varName` and remove the `;` at the end of if statement

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon after the if statement